# How to get number of draft posts without --drafts

Tags: jekyll

I am using Jekyll, writing both drafts and posts. I have many drafts (hidden) but only a few finished posts (published).

```
$ tree
...
├── _drafts
│   ├── <a bunch>
...
├── _posts
│   ├── <a few>
```

I would like to show the number of drafts (currently in `_drafts`) without publishing their contents.

This requires accessing "draft post" data in Liquid (Ruby), and while `site.posts` is defined, `site.drafts` is not.

How can I programmatically access drafts, without preprocessing?

---

Answer (score 1):

I use the following in `custom-head.html` to mark rendered pages as drafts. Maybe you could salvage something from it.

```html
{% assign dir_elements = page.path | split: "/" %}
{% if dir_elements[0] == '_drafts' %}
  <meta name="jekyll-type" content="draft" />
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is:

- Move all drafts from `_drafts` to `_posts`. This way, they can be accessed via `site.posts`.
- In the YAML front matter of drafts, add `tags: draft`.
- In Liquid: filter out all posts with tag `draft` from being displayed, but count their number.

This solution should work fine, but I'd like to keep drafts separate from posts somehow so that they can be distinguished at a glance. Maybe adding a `_posts/drafts` subdirectory is the best-of-both solution.